# php7.2 and oci8 conflict

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

After migrating server to php7.2 from php5.4 oci8 is not working.
Upgrade procedure:
1. remove php packages 
2. Install php72u-common + some extras.

result:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 16:53:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I couldn't find any useful info in google. Please help (this is production server)

EDIT:
It's for sure not about wrong php.ini
extension=oci8.so 
output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

extension=oci8 
output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete)) in Unknown on line 0
```

/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so exsists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file`

You've got an extra `.so` at the end of your string there. You've probably got this in your php.ini:

```
extension = oci8.so
```

Change it to:

```
extension = oci8
```

Comment: Already tried this is not the case .... php when do not find extension or extension is not working it adding .so. The problem is that something is missing and I have no idea what

Comment: Yes, it adds *one* .so, which means you have `oci8.so` in your php.ini file *and* you don't actually have the oci8.so file.

Comment: Ok noted. Perhaps you are still using the oci8.so from 5.4?

Comment: oracle client was installed via rpms from Oracle site I also reinstalled it, Still not working

Comment: `_zend_list_delete` does not exist in PHP 7.2 -- it last existed in 5.6 and was removed in 7.0. So your oci8.so file was compiled against a version of PHP different than what you're currently running.

Comment: indeed! now it's working. Update your answer with remving oci8.so file + install pear1u + pecl install oci8 ( and restart apache of course) so I can mark it as correct answer :)